# Why doesn't onload event work as an event of my DIV?

Tags: javascript, events, onload

I am trying to refer to a JS function for some of my DIVs. For various reasons, I need to place an on+event inside the HTML tag of these DIVs. So my code looks like this

```
<div id="item1" onload="HideME(this)">item 1</div>
<div id="item2" onclick="HideME(this)">item 2</div>
<script >
function HideME(which1) {
            alert (which1.innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

As you see, I have two DIVs in this code, the first one given an onclick event, which works fine, and the second one, is given an onload event which doesn't do anything. Why?

P.S.
Please help me with correcting this method of calling my function (onload in the tag line), not other methods if there are any.
Many thanks

Comment: It seem as if you want to hide that first div on page load. Why not do it with CSS ? `#item1 {display: none;}`

Comment: I always though that you can only attach the onload attribute to the body, or in js to the window

Comment: to Luca: According to the references I have read, onload can be attributed to any element. Of course in this case, I need it to be given to the DIVs, which must work fine.

Comment: to Ludovit Mydla: That's not the point of this question of course, but in fact, in my actual code, I am manipulating the CSS using the same way you just mentioned, but the problem here is that the function is not called using onload (although it works fine with onclick)

Comment: What references are those? ((use @ to mention a user))

Comment: @SeyedMostafa according to [specs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp), `onload` works on `<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>` tags. So it won't work on plain div

Comment: @LudovitMydla Thank you. Very helpful. Didn't notice that myself. This actually answers this question, so if you post it as an answer, not a comment, people could find the answer as accepted. Also, What can I do if onload is not accepted here?

Comment: @SeyedMostafa The question is, why you need it to work on page load? So that we avoid [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) What do you really want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a proper answer: according to [specs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp), onload works on `<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>` tags. So it won't work on plain div

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to call a function directly AFTER your element

Example:

```
<div id="item1">Item 1</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   HideMe('item1');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt I think that will solve my problem. Very useful indeed.